# Is there any way to control the light value of the Apple logo on a MacBook?

Tags: devices, apple

I'd like to mess around a bit with controlling the Apple logo on the outside of my MacBook Pro from Ubuntu. (I'd like to hook it up to my music and have it light up and down with the decibels :])

Does anyone know what this device is and how I could control it? Is it a device in `/sys/devices`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes.  it's a translucent piece of plastic whose brightness directly correlates to the brightness of your display.

All you need is something that will dim and brighten your display in time to your music.

Comment: Weird. I always thought it was a separate device. I guess that answers my question.